# Netezza add new field for first record value of the day in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm trying to add new columns of first values of the day for location and weight.

For instance, the original data format is:

```
id         dttm         location     weight
--------------------------------------------
1     1/1/20 11:10:00     A           40
1     1/1/20 19:07:00     B           41.1
2     1/1/20 08:01:00     B           73.2
2     1/1/20 21:00:00     B           73.2
2     1/2/20 10:03:00     C           74
```

I want each id to have only one day record, such as:

```
id         dttm         location     weight
--------------------------------------------
1     1/1/20 11:10:00     A           40
2     1/1/20 08:01:00     B           73.2
2     1/2/20 10:03:00     C           74
```

I have other columns in my data set that I'm using location and weight to create, so I don't think I can just filter for 'first' records of the day.. Is it possible to write query to recognize first record of the day for those two columns and create new column with those values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, ddtm::date order by dttm) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```